# I am struggling to get some of my figures labelled as schemes

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

Underneath some of the images in my document I would like the caption to read scheme1.1 etc. instead of figure1.1, I was wondering if it was possible to do this selectively as I use Chemdraw to draw the figures and schemes and would rather not use chemfig. Thank you for the help.

Comment: How have you set up schemes in your document?

Comment: You can define a new floating environment yourself (with the `newfloat` package or KOMA-Script or...)  or use a package like `chemscheme` or `chemmacros` both of which define a `scheme` float.

Comment: You should do what Clemens and Joseph say. But, with `caption` package, put this right after the `\begin{figure}` → `\captionsetup{name=Scheme}`

Answer (score 3):

Three possibilities:

1. load `chemscheme` and use the `scheme` environment for your schemes:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{chemscheme}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{scheme}
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \caption{This is a scheme and not a figure!}
   \end{scheme}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. load `chemmacros` and its module `scheme` and use the `scheme` environment for your schemes:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{chemmacros}
   \chemsetup{modules={scheme}}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{scheme}
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \caption{This is a scheme and not a figure!}
   \end{scheme}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. define a `scheme` float on your own, for example by using the `newfloat` package:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{newfloat}
   \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
     fileext = los ,
     listname = {List of Schemes} ,
     name = Scheme
   ]{scheme}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{scheme}
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \caption{This is a scheme and not a figure!}
   \end{scheme}
   \end{document}
   ```

   Depending on the document class and packages you're loading other possibilities for defining floats may be used. `memoir` has a mechanism of its own, KOMA-Script classes have `\DeclareNewTOC`, there are the `float` and the `floatrow` packages…

All three examples give

[image]