# How to change figure labels and numbers?

Tags: floats

I am compiling a document at the moment and I need some of the figures to be labelled "Scheme x: (caption)" rather than figure. Furthermore it would be great if these could have a separate numbering system, I.e. their numbers (e.g. x above) acsend separately for figures and "schemes" through the document. Any help greatly appreciated. Sorry I'm not giving any detail of my document here but font have it with me at the moment, preamble is fairly long due to various other formatting requirements for theses at my uni.

Comment: Hi Rieve and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: you can use the `float` or the `newfloat` packages

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274814/i-am-struggling-to-get-some-of-my-figures-labelled-as-schemes/275193#275193 helps